# Why are all posts in “real-time” tab displayed as "active 5/6 mins go" after initial load?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

**UPDATE:**
As of today (Aug. 13, 2015) I can confirm real-time tab is working flawlessly! I can see the expected behavior and everything is working as it should. I don't know when this was fixed but thank you for fixing this!

---

I just noticed an interesting thing on the Stack Exchange [**real-time tab**](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) posts display. The very first-time when the listing gets loaded, it correctly shows the time in secs giving you the real-time feel. You get very little time to notice this (you can always hit the "reload" button) change. But as soon as the next question is loaded in the list, all of the posts are displayed with "active 5 mins go". If you scroll down further, the little older posts will show "active 6 mins go", etc.

Why does the real-time gets replaced with static value after the initial load? Why not leave the time as it is? Or, does this belong to [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) category? Can anyone please explain.

**Does not work:** (Mac OS)

I tried it on three different browsers (after removing cache and history) on my MacBook Pro (OS X Yosemite Ver. 10.10.2) and all of them had the same problem i.e. worked perfectly on the initial load but later when the new question came in, all of the posts got active 5 or 6 mins. ago status. Please see the first three screenshots below for the Mac OS browser's output.

Works ***perfectly*** (from *just now* to *secs*. to *mins*.) on Windows 8.1 OS with Internet Explorer 11. (see the 4th screenshot below)

** Right-click on screenshots below and open image in new tab to see the full version.

Chrome Incognito window Screenshot: (Version. 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit))

> [image]

Firefox Screenshot: (Version 39.0)

> [image]

Safari Screenshot: (Version 8.0.7 (10600.7.12))

> [image]

Internet Explorer Screenshot: (Version 11.0.9600.17905)

> [image]

Comment: No-repro on Iceweasel 31.8. The first load shows "X secs" or "just now". When the auto loading of a new post is activated, the post time of the previous posts (under the new one) are advanced a few seconds, this happens every time a new posts is auto added to the list. Even if I let loads of new posts be auto added, scrolling to the bottom one is only posted "1 min ago"

Comment: @James I am using Google Chrome. Just tried Firefox and Safari and its shows "active 5 mins ago" ...

Comment: @James nope... same result even after clearing cache in all of them... Do you have Chrome or FF?

Comment: Iceweasel is a fork of Firefox (I'm on Debian). I won't install Chrome though (sorry) IMO it's buggy/crappy/prone to security issues. Someone else with those browsers will report soon. Might be worth editing your question and adding the exact browser versions you repro with.

Comment: Working fine for me on Chrome Version 43.0.2357.134 (64-bit) FF 39.0 for OSX.

Comment: Added screenshots for the reference

Comment: Please add a [status-completed] tag to this question as it's been fixed!